# External dependencies are incorrectly bundled in rollup.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, rollupjs, code-splitting

I am trying to create 2 separate builds using [rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org/): `application.js` and `dependencies.js`, contaning my application code, and common library code (`react`, `react-dom`, etc.), respectively.

The docs say I should be able to simply use `externals: ['react', 'react-dom']` and have it work - but when I inspect the resulting bundle, I still wind up having the full body of both libs included. Here's my example `app.config.js`, which I call using `rollup -c app.config.js`:

What am I doing wrong?

```
import babel       from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import replace     from 'rollup-plugin-replace'
import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'
import { keys }    from 'lodash'    

const PRODUCTION = (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development') === 'production'
const ENVIRONMENT = JSON.stringify(PRODUCTION ? 'production' : 'development')

const EXTERNALS = {
  'react': 'React',
  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
}

const plugins = [
  replace({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': ENVIRONMENT }),
  babel({
    babelrc: false,
    exclude: ['node_modules/**', '**/*.json'],
    presets: ['es2015-rollup', 'react'],
  }),
  commonjs({
    ignoreGlobal: false,
    include: ['node_modules/**'],
  }),
  nodeResolve({
    browser: true,
    jsnext: true,
    main: true,
    preferBuiltins: false,
  }),
]

if (PRODUCTION) {
  plugins.push(uglify())
}

export default {
  entry: 'source/application.js',
  exports: 'none',
  external: keys(EXTERNALS),
  globals: EXTERNALS,
  plugins,
  targets: [{
    dest: 'build/js/application.js',
    format: 'iife',
    sourceMap: !PRODUCTION,
    sourceMapFile: '/js/application.js',
  }],
  treeshake: true,
}
```

Comment: try using webpack.. i find it much easier

Answer (score 6):

The answer I found was to include an additional argument to the `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` plugin call, as follows:

```
nodeResolve({
  ignoreGlobal: false,
  include: ['node_modules/**'],
  skip: keys(EXTERNALS), // <<-- skip: ['react', 'react-dom']
}),
```

This is apparently needed, so that the `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` plugin knows to `skip` importing these external dependencies when other `node_modules` included libraries import them.

e.g.: `import someReactLib from 'some-react-lib'` which uses `import React from 'react'`. Without the `skip` language, this seems to result in pulling in `React` to the overall bundle.

Comment: That's quite obscure default behavior, have you found that being documented somewhere? Could you provide a link?

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work anymore, and even after adding in the main rollup externals I'm still seeing a package being incorrectly bundled...extremely frustrating.

Comment: For the record: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#external